# What type I should add to class constructor received as parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I am creating my own class decorator(`classLogger`) in TypeScript. In `classLogger` I am recaving class constructor as a parameter of my decorator and I am wondering what type I should add to this parameter(`originalConstructor`) ?

I was trying something like this:

```js
export const classLogger = <T>(originalConstructor: (...args: any[]) => T) => {
```

But then I van not acces `.name` property of my `originalConstructor` and also I can not use **new** on `originalConstructor`.

**classLogger**

```js
export const classLogger = (originalConstructor: any) => {
    const newConstructor = (...args: any[]) => { // same story here what type i should add to newConstructor
        console.log(`New [${originalConstructor.name}], has been created`);
        return new originalConstructor(...args)
    };
    newConstructor.prototype = originalConstructor.prototype;
    return newConstructor;
};
```

**Warrior**

```js
import {classLogger} from "./decorators/classLogger";

@classLogger
export class Warrior {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    challengeOpponent(message: string): string {
        return `Hello I am ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}. I want to challenge you! ${message}`;
    }
}
```

**PS**. I am also getting this error:

> Error:(3, 1) TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
>     Type '{ (...args: any[]): any; prototype: any; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof Warrior'.
>       Type '{ (...args: any[]): any; prototype: any; }' provides no match for the signature 'new (firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number): Warrior'.

In `Warrior.ts` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for a constructor would be:

```
 { new(...args: any[]): any, name: string }
```

I'd type your code as:

```
 export function classLogger<T extends { new(...args: any[]): any }>(originalConstructor: T) {
  const newConstructor: T = (...args: any[]) => { 
    console.log(`New [${(originalConstructor as any).name}], has been created`);
    return new originalConstructor(...args)
  };
  newConstructor.prototype = originalConstructor.prototype;
  return newConstructor;
};
```

Comment: There is a ```FunctionConstructor``` type but it also doesn't has a ```.name``` property. Maybe I should add ```IClassConstructor``` inteface which will extend ```FunctionConstructor``` interface and add ```name: string``` property ?

Comment: No, `FunctionConstructor` is the global `Function` object.

Comment: Ye but actually class constructor is also a function.

Comment: Oh, then add a typecast.